# Speeding up postscript image print

Tags: performance, printing, postscript

I am developing an application that prints an image via generating postscript output and sending it to the printer. So I convert my image to jpg, then to ASCII85 string, append this data to postscript file and send it to the printer.

Output looks like:

```
%!
{/DeviceRGB setcolorspace
/T currentfile/ASCII85Decode filter def
/F T/DCTDecode filter def
<</ImageType 1/Width 3600/Height 2400/BitsPerComponent
8/ImageMatrix[7.809 0 0 -8.053 0 2400]/Decode
[0 1 0 1 0 1]/DataSource F>> image F closefile T closefile}
exec
s4IA0!"_al8O`[\!<E1.!+5d,s5<tI7<iNY!!#_f!%IsK!!iQ0!?(qA!!!!"!!!".!?2"B!!!!"!!!
---------------------------------------------------------------
ASCII85 data
---------------------------------------------------------------
bSKs4I~>
showpage
```

My goal now is to speed up this code. Now it takes about 14 seconds from sending .ps to the printer to the moment printer actually starts printing the page (for the 2MB file).

Why is it so slow?

Maybe I can reformat the image so printer doesn't need to perform an affine transform of the image?

Maybe i can use better image encoding?

Any tutorials, clues or advices would be valuable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One reason its slow is because JPEG is an expensive compression filter. Try using Flate instead. Don't ASCII85 encode the image, send it as binary, that reduces transmission time and removes another filter. Note that jpeg is a lossy compression, so by 'converting to jpeg' you are also sacrificing quality.

You can **reduce** the amount of effort the printer goes to by creating/scaling the image (before creating the PostScript) so that each image sample matches one pixel in device space. On the other hand, if you are scaling an image up, this means you will need to send more image data to the printer. But usually these days the data connection is fast.

However this is usually hard to do and often defeated by the fact that the printer may not be able to print to the edge of the media, and so may scale the marking operations by a small amount, so that the content fits on the printable area. Its usually pretty hard to figure out if that's going on.

Your ImageMatrix is, well, odd..... It isn't a 1:1 scaling and floating point scale factors are really going to slow down the mapping from user space to device space. And you have a lot of samples to map.

You could also map the image samples into PostScript device space (so that bottom left is at 0,0 instead of top left) which would mean you wouldn't have to flip the CTM In the y axis.

But in short, trying to play with the scale factors is probably not worth it, and most printers optimise these transformations anyway.

The colour model of the printer is usually CMYK, so by sending an RGB image you are forcing the printer to do a colour conversion on every sample in the image. For your image that's more than 8.5 million conversions.

Comment: Thank you for your advices! My image is 3600x2400 and the page resolution is 3600x2400 (6x4 inches, 600 dpi), but postscript uses 1/72 inch units, so, as I understand from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17716915/4974495) answer, I still should use non-1:1 scaling in CTM. Am I wrong? Is it any way to avoid this?

Comment: PostScript units are indeed 1/72 inch, so scale factors are difficult to calculate. You didn't mention the resolution of the device in your question, so I was unable to tell if the scaling would be 1:1 or not.